# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.' in IFormFile.CopyTo

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a situation where I need to create the FormFile from an image and then I need back MemoryStream from FormFile. The MemoryStream from a file is in some other place. I have just made this as a sample to produce the issue.

```
private IFormFile ReturnFormFile(Image image, string thumbnailName)
    {
        IFormFile file = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            file = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "name", thumbnailName);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(memStream);// System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

            Byte[] fileData = memStream.ToArray();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: `ms` is being disposed the moment it goes out of scope of its using. `FormFile` is evidently just holding a reference to that stream rather than making a copy (which makes sense). The obvious solution is not to dispose of it until you want to.

Comment: `using` gets compiled into `try { } finally { }`  you can declare the memory stream as a variable variable belonging to ReturnFormFile instead maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
private IFormFile ReturnFormFile(Image image, string thumbnailName)
    {
        IFormFile file = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            file = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "name", thumbnailName);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(memStream);// System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

                Byte[] fileData = memStream.ToArray();
            }
            return file;
        }
       
    }
```